# jQuery AJAX URL's not relative

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I have the same problem as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7713859/jquery-ajax-reference-mvc-controller-url-from-app-root) question. In an MVC5 single page application, All my AJAX requests look like this:

```
$.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: 'ControllerName/MethodName',
       data: {foo : 'bar'},
       dataType: 'json',
       cache: false,
       })
```

If I'm on the front page of my application, of which the URL would be:

```
http://localhost:62989/
```

This AJAX method would produce a call to:

```
http://localhost:62989/ControllerName/MethodName
```

However, when I'm on a different page (with unit tests), such as:

```
http://localhost:62989/Home/UnitTests
```

This AJAX method would call to:

```
http://localhost:62989/Home/ControllerName/MethodName
```

Which doesn't work. Replacing 'ControllerName/MethodName' with:

```
'@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName")'
```

does not work for me. In Firebug, this shows up as:

```
GET http://localhost:62989/Home/@Url.Action(%22MethodName%20%22ControllerName%22)
```

And using the answer in the comments, which is:

```
window.location.pathname + 'ControllerName/MethodName'
```

Doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I assume this - `'@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName")' ` - does not work for you because your code is in a `*.js` file which is not interpreted by Razor? If so, add the `Url.Action` value as a data parameter to the element which raises the event and read it from it before making the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName")` in external javascript files. This works only inside Razor views. So for example in your Razor view you could set a javascript variable:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myUrl = '@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName")';
</script>
```

that you could have used in your external js:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: myUrl,
   data: {foo : 'bar'},
   dataType: 'json',
   cache: false,
});
```

Obviously this is rarely necessary because you write those AJAX requests in the callbacks of some events of existing DOM elements such as HTML forms or anchors. So you already have all the necessary information about the url in the DOM element.

Let's suppose that you are unobtrusively AJAXifying an anchor element:

```
@Html.ActionLink("click me", "MethodName", "ControllerName", new { foo = "bar" }, new { id = "myLink" })
```

So you already have a proper url in this anchor that you could AJAXify:

```
$('#myLink').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: this.href,
       dataType: 'json',
       cache: false,
    });
    return false;
});
```

Notice how I've used `this.href` to extract the correct url from the anchor. The same stands true for form elements for which you can subscribe to the `.submit` event and extract the `action` attribute.

And if for some reason you are manipulating some DOM element that doesn't have the notion of an url you could always use HTML5 data-* attributes:

```
<div id="myDiv" data-url="@Url.Action("MethodName", "ControllerName")">click me</div>
```

and then in your separate js file:

```
$('#myDiv').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
       type: 'GET',
       url: $(this).data('url'),
       dataType: 'json',
       cache: false,
    });
});
```

And that's pretty much the philosophy - always use server side helpers when dealing with urls in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me out! I need to edit the URL's before they get sent to the client.